# Calculate seconds minutes and days ago in shell

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a timestamp that saves a user's last access information like

Time => 14:15:05 PM

Day => 08/23/2023

Based on this saved information, I would like to write a command that returns how much time has passed compared to the time at now 15:15:14 PM on 8/23/2023 as the format below

=> 30 seconds ago

=> 12 minutes ago

=> 4 hours ago

=> 11 days ago

=> 1 year ago

what I've tried so far

> date -d '7:00:00 AM - 15 minutes' '+%H:%M'

but this only returns 15 minutes ago based on the prescribed time of 7:00:00 AM an already defined time and decreasing its value to 15 minutes ago.

**What I want is to calculate based on the actual time of now (23/08/2023 15:15:14 PM) and say how much time has passed since 14:15:05 on 23/08/2023 or the day before 22/08/2023.**

Comment: You get the epoch seconds of a timestamp: `past=$(date -d "..." "+%s")` and the current epoch seconds `now=$(date "+%s")`, and do some arithmetic to get the difference.

Comment: thank you for your response but it is still not what I am wanting, I need him to say with baae at the time save and with the local tempo do carimbo hora/dia of now at the moment how much time has passed in minutes hours or days or even years as I mentioned in the examples like 12 minutes ago etc ...

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. You will need to give more examples. Show all the input parameters and the desired output.

Comment: @gleen would be the 14:15:05 time stamp that is saved in an hour folder.txt and then calculate how much time has already passed compared to the time now of the result of the hour folder.txt and reporting 15 minutes ago or 2 hours ago based on the actual time now.

Comment: sorry I understand English but I wrote in another language haha

Comment: Duplicate question. This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442175/2172543)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` command cannot calculate durations.

It's essentially what I commented before:

1. you have timestamp one: `ts1=$( date -d "08/23/2023 14:15:05" "+%s" )`
2. you get a second timestamp, however you want `ts2=$( date -d "now - 15 minutes" "+%s" )`
3. calculate the differences in different ways:

   ```bash
   $ printf '%(%F %T)T minus %(%F %T)T is %d %s\n' "$ts1" "$ts2" "$((ts1-ts2))" seconds
   2023-08-23 14:15:05 minus 2023-07-24 19:07:25 is 2574460 seconds

   $ printf '%(%F %T)T minus %(%F %T)T is %d %s\n' "$ts1" "$ts2" "$(( (ts1-ts2) / 60 ))" minutes
   2023-08-23 14:15:05 minus 2023-07-24 19:07:25 is 42907 minutes

   $ printf '%(%F %T)T minus %(%F %T)T is %d %s\n' "$ts1" "$ts2" "$(( (ts1-ts2) / (60*60) ))" hours
   2023-08-23 14:15:05 minus 2023-07-24 19:07:25 is 715 hours

   $ printf '%(%F %T)T minus %(%F %T)T is %d %s\n' "$ts1" "$ts2" "$(( (ts1-ts2) / (60*60*24) ))" days
   2023-08-23 14:15:05 minus 2023-07-24 19:07:25 is 29 days
   ```

I think our misunderstanding is how to accomplish step 2.

If you don't want to do it manually, lots of languages have date modules that can do durations:
[perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Esubtract_datetime($datetime)),
[python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fold)